# ntp doesn't work in raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, ntp

the problem is my raspberry pi 3 doesn't show the correct date and time.i edit this file: `sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf` with correct server addresses and i try this commands :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
sudo ntpd -q-g
```

but i get this error:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpd: illegal option -- -
ntpd - NTP daemon program - Ver. 4.2.8p10
Usage:  ntpd [ -<flag> [<val>] | --<name>[{=| }<val>] ]... \
    [ <server1> ... <serverN> ]
Try 'ntpd --help' for more information.
```

how can i correct this error?
thank you

Comment: Raspbian doesn't use `ntpd`

Comment: @Milliways it does run NTP when you eliminate the timesyncd junk. I have one raspberry running an NTP server and seventeen running an NTP client getting the time from the local server.

Comment: @Dougie `timesyncd` is the Debian default used to synchronize the local system clock with a remote Network Time Protocol server and works for the vast bulk of users. There is no reason to think the OP has installed `ntpd`; it seems more likely to be following an obsolete tutorial. Unless this is clarified answering seems pointless, and the question would still not be Raspberry Pi specific

Answer (score 5):

Run it as `sudo ntpd -q -g` note that space between the options.